# Why won't Alt+Shift switch languages in Microsoft Word?

Tags: windows, keyboard, microsoft-word, microsoft-office, language

I have Windows 7 RTM, Office 2007 SP1, and a computer with English and Hebrew languages installed. In most programs (e.g. notepad), <kbd>Left Alt</kbd>+<kbd>Shift</kbd> switches from Hebrew to English and vice versa.

In Word, it also usually works, but **sometimes** pressing <kbd>Left Alt</kbd>+<kbd>Shift</kbd> just won't do anything.

Is this a bug in Windows? Word?

Answer (score 2):

I had the same problem but then I found out that in Windows keyboard settings I've added another keyboad (Serbian) under English (United States), and not beside it. So I vent and set it all up again the right way and now it works. So instead of:

English (United States)

> - Keyboard
>
>   - US
>   - Serbian (Latin)

Now I have:

> English (United States)
>
> - Keyboard
>
>   - US
>
> Serbian (Latin)
>
> - Keyboard
>
>   - Serbian (Latin)

Answer (score 1):

Works for me, at least. You can try changing the keystroke to switch input languages in

> Regional and Language Options > Keyboard and Languages > Change keyboards > Advanced Key Settings.

Maybe a different combination might work.

Comment: Works for me too. Seems rather strange.

Answer (score 1):

In Regional and Language -> Advanced Key Settings, create a shortcut like <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>0</kbd> to change to Hebrew (not between languages).

Answer (score 0):

This happened to me recently. Tried the switch, nothing. Tried again, worked fine. Guess it's a bug (I'm on W7 RC).

I'd recommend trying the alt+shift method, then (if necessary) doing the slow way through regional options. I think this might re-enable the hotkey method.